# Ошибка компиляции C++: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь не так. По идее, программа должна в зависимости от введённых сторон треугольника сообщать, существует такой, или нет.  Нужно было выполнить задание с помощью вложенных `if`. Но выдаёт ошибку:

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token if ((a + b) <= с)

Что это значит?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a, b, c;

  cout << "Введите величины сторон треугольника a, b, c: ";
  cin >> a >> b >> c;
  if ((a + b) <= с)
  {
    if ((a + c) <= b)
    {
      if ((b + c) <= a)
      {
        cout << "Не существует";
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "Существует";
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      cout << "Существует";
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    cout << "Существует";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Пишите английские буквы в именах переменных.

Хоть русская «с» очень похожа на английскую «c», для компилятора это разные вещи.

**P. S.** PutnoSwitcher?  :)

**P. P. S.** Кстати, всё равно вычисления логических значений сокращенные, так что проще было бы написать так:

```
if ((a + b > c) && (a + c > b) && (b + c > a))
    std::cout << "Существует";
else
    std::cout << "Не существует";
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я и не заметила.